# Is this "possibly-uninitialized" compiler error a false alarm? [rustc 1.51.0]

Tags: rust, compiler-errors, compiler-bug

I was hit with the **possibly-uninitialized variable** error, although I'm convinced that this should never be the case.
(The rustc --version is `rustc 1.51.0 (2fd73fabe 2021-03-23)`)

```rust
fn example(discriminant: bool) {
    let value;
    if discriminant {
        value = 0;
    }

    // more code [...]

    if discriminant {
        println!("{}", value);
    }
}
```

Here's the error message:

```
    error[E0381]: borrow of possibly-uninitialized variable: `value`
      --> src/raytracing/intersect.rs:8:24
       |
    10 |         println!("{}", value);
       |                        ^^^^^ use of possibly-uninitialized `value`
```

### Reasoning

I did expect the example to compile (*even though seperating the `if`-blocks as shown isn't "good style" IMHO*):

- As `discriminant` is immutable, I expect the second `if` block to never execute without the first.
- Therefore, the variable should always be defined at the time of borrow in `println!()`.

#### Possible mitigation

The error can be 'silenced' by initializing `value` with a temporary value.
I strongly disagree with this approach because

- a temporary value could be wrong in a mathematical sense due to it being impossible to compute in other code paths.
- Also, this could hide the fact that the value isn't properly defined during development, limiting the compiler's abilities to signal errors.

### Question

Can someone clarify if this case is intended behaviour or maybe a compiler bug?

Comment: The code is fine, of course.  It's normal among compilers for warnings about uninitialized variables to have false positives in cases like this, which is why it says "possibly".  There's no way to have a warning that's 100% correct in all cases, because that's the halting problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not the first person to see this behavior, and generally I would not consider it a bug.  In your case, the condition is very simple and obvious, and it's easy for you and me to reason about this condition.  However, in general, the condition does not need to be obvious and, for example, the second case could have additional conditions that are hard to reason about, even though the code is correct.

Moreover, the kind of analysis you want the compiler to do (determine which code is reachable based on conditions) is usually only done when the compiler is optimizing.  Therefore, even if the compiler had support for this kind of analysis, it probably wouldn't work in debug mode.  It also doesn't work in all cases even in the best optimizing compilers and static analysis tools.

If you have a philosophical objection to initializing a dummy value in this case, you can use an `Option`:

```
fn example(discriminant: bool) {
    let value = if discriminant {
        Some(0)
    } else {
        None
    };

    // more code [...]

    if discriminant {
        println!("{}", value.unwrap());
    }
}
```

In this case, your value is always initialized, and in the second portion, you're asserting that it contains a suitable non-`None` value.  If you're in release mode, the compiler may be able to determine that your code is correct and optimize it to omit the `Option` (or it may not).

Comment: `let value = discriminant.then(|| 0); ... if let Some(v) = value { ... }`

Comment: Sure, I would write this as `if let Some(v)`, but that does read differently than what I've written, and I chose to keep it similar to the original code on purpose.  While you _can_ use `bool::then`, it's relatively new, and even though it will work for the OP, I prefer to write code that's a little more compatible to help folks who aren't using the latest Rust.

Comment: Thanks, I have understood that the compiler can't solve this in the general case! And your example made it clear that I essentially could use an option instead of some sentinel value.

Comment: I think this answer is confusing due to bringing in the optimizer. Flow-sensitive type-checking (or in this case, liveness checking) exists, and Rust already supports it partly -- you can see it in action in loops. The optimizer has, really, nothing to do with that.